# difference and usage of subsetting on i or on j with .SD

Tags: r, data.table

Is there any difference in subsetting on `i` vs `j` using `.SD` such as in the following snippet? And in which case would be one preferred over the other, as they seem pretty identical to me.

```
library(data.table)   
dat <- data.table(c("a", "a", "", "b", "b", "c", "d"),
                  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                  c(11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 14),
                  i = 1:7)
identical(dat[, .SD[V2 == 1]], dat[V2 == 1])
# TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe a microsecond or two? I also get TRUE for `identical( dat[, .SD[V2 == 1,V3]], dat[V2 == 1, V3] )`

Comment: .SD includes all columns not included in the grouping (unless .SDcols is used to specify a subset of columns). In your case you've not grouped by a variable, nor used .SDcols, so there is no difference.

Comment: If you have a `by=`, then `i` is certainly a lot better because `[` has a lot of overhead and would be called for each group. Otherwise, I think 42- is right.